# Failing to make an array of Images in Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, spyder

I am trying to create an array of .jpg files, but the compiler is not building the array

More specifically, my problem is that a public folder, whose path is defined as the object path, is not accessible by my Python compiler [Spyder]. However, the folder, and its respective files are all public and open access to everyone. What might be the reason that my computer cannot access the images?

Code 1 is an simple function to find and access the file path I want, and the Kernal results show what is failing.

Code 2 is the syntax for the isolated error in the program I am applying the open() method. Kernal results depict compiler failure.

***Code 1:***

```
import os

path = r'C:/Users/BeckerLab/Pictures/Final_Sample_Set/Right2'

try:
    os.path.exists(path)
    if (True):
        R = open(path)
        R.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("file does not exist")
```

***Kernal for Code 1:***

```
!runfile('C:/Users/BeckerLab/untitled6.py', wdir='C:/Users/BeckerLab')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\BeckerLab\untitled6.py", line 8, in <module>
    R = open(path)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/BeckerLab/Pictures/Final_Sample_Set/Right2'
```

***Code 2:***

```
import os

rightSamples = [open(file, 'r+') for file in os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Public/Right2')]
```

***Kernal Results for Code 2:***

```
!runfile('C:/Users/BeckerLab/almost.py', wdir='C:/Users/BeckerLab')
2020-04-05 12:59:28
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\BeckerLab\almost.py", line 46, in <module>
    rightSamples = [open(file, 'r+') for file in os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Public/Right2')]

  File "C:\Users\BeckerLab\almost.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
    rightSamples = [open(file, 'r+') for file in os.listdir(r'C:/Users/Public/Right2')]

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R1.JPG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your condition is:

```py
os.path.exists(path)
if (True):
```

which will always be true. Maybe try:

```py
if (os.path.exists(path)):
```

Try moving the files to another directory like `'D:/../BeckerLab/untitled6.py'`